# Is an object of a certain type

Tags: vb.net, serialization, visual-studio-2012, object-type

How can I check if an object is of a certain type in a function. Here is my code:

```
Public Function IsSerializedObjectAValidObjectType(Of ObjectType)(FileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ObjectToCheck As New Object
    ObjectToCheck = OpenObjectFromFile(FileName)
    Return ObjectToCheck.GetType Is ObjectType
End Function
```

The following code gets an object from a file.

```
ObjectToCheck = OpenObjectFromFile(FileName)
```

Comment: Just a minor point:  You are creating a new Object (using the New keyword) and then immediately throwing that newly created object away and replacing it with the instance returned from OpenObjectFromFile.  You can save the creation of an unnecessary object by omitting the New keyword in this code sample.  Just use this line:  `Dim ObjetToCheck As Object = OpenObjectFromFile(FileName)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Function IsSerializedObjectAValidObjectType(Of T)(FileName As String) As Boolean
      Dim ObjectToCheck As New Object
      ObjectToCheck = OpenObjectFromFile(FileName)
      Return TypeOf ObjectToCheck.GetType Is T
End Function
```